# Error when asking for Location using expo-location

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I've beeing using `expo-location` since the beginning of my project, and didn't have any problem with this library.

And it is implemented as follow:

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

let { status } = await Location.getForegroundPermissionsAsync();
console.log('STATUS', status);
if (status === 'granted' && !getLocationPermissionStatus) {
          setLocationPermissionStatus('granted');
}
```

But since today, when I've changed my machine and downloaded my project and setup everything again, the project is throwing this error when the notification is called.

`Error: Permissions module not found. Are you sure that Expo modules are properly linked? checkPermissions$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:460494:32`

I'd like some help on this issue.

ps.: I've `expo-notifications` being called on the same block of code and its not causing any issue.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you've run `expo install expo-location`?

Comment: @JoelRummel yes, I have run this , and `npx pod-install` right after

Comment: Facing the same problem. Were you able to resolve this?